# How to add a dependency on a Preference in Android?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I write dynamic preferences and I have an IllegalStateException with this code :

```
String key = "pref_key1";

CheckBoxPreference pref1 = new CheckBoxPreference(getActivity());
pref1.setKey(key);

Preference pref2 = new Preference(getActivity());
pref2.setKey("pref_key2");
pref2.setDependency(key);
```

The error is :

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dependency "pref_key1" not found for preference "pref_key2"`

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: `setDependency()` will not work until both preferences are part of some "preference hierarchy". Having them both belong to the same `PreferenceScreen` may suffice.

Comment: I add dependency after the two preferences have the same `PreferenceScreen` and it work prefectly. Thanks !